# Is there an if statement that can determine if a post in the loop is the last post?

Tags: posts

For example, inside the loop could i do something like this

```
if lastpost { 
}
else {
}
```

Answer (score 35):

```
if ($wp_query->current_post +1 == $wp_query->post_count) {
    // this is the last post
}
```

Change $wp_query to your own query variable if you made a new WP_Query object.

Comment: great this will bring the oldest post in a loop. What If I want to retrieve the latest post?

Comment: Then write your query to retrieve only the latest post.

Answer (score 3):

I've coded up a quick little example for you. Should explain how to get the first and last post in a WP loop.

```
    $post_count = 0;
    $total = count($posts);

    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        if ($post_count == 1 AND $post_count !== $total)
        {
            // This is the first post
        }

        if ($post_count == $total)
        {
            // This is the last item
        }

        $post_count++;

    endwhile;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!get_next_post_link()) { 
    echo 'the last post here'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!get_previous_post_link()) { 
    echo 'the last post here'; 
}
```

OR

```
if (get_next_post_link()) { 
    echo 'the last post here'; 
}
```